# ui-router preload app (entire or partial)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

The application I'm developing uses "angular.js" + "ui-router" + "bootstrap". Many states and nested views. There are also some images related to templates and, finally, animated transitions placed there to generate feeling of fluidity.

Under ideal network conditions, the application works reasonably well.

Under poor network conditions, it is bad. Sometimes animation flicks, sometimes there is a pause between the user action and the response of the interface. (for instance: the start of an animation). The feeling of flow can not be achieved.

The problems are noted when "ui-router" changes its state, the application seems to lock or flicks animations or there are sudden jumps.

The application is to be used from devices with limited bandwidth due to its geographical location.

Can I preload all or part of the application, including images and others assets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can concatenate and minify all JS & CSS assets (if you are not already doing so). I use grunt-neuter for dependency management. You can also bundle all the dependent libraries together (I use grunt-usemin).
2. I have not tried to bundle all the templates into one file, but that should also be possible. In that case, you would wrap each template within `<script type="text/template"></script>` blocks, have everything in DOM, and pluck out individual templates and provide to each route. This should totally eliminate flicker.
3. For image assets, there are grunt plugins such as grunt-spritefiles that takes a bunch of images, and create a sprite, which then can be used within your CSS.

These are some of the techniques I can think of. However, the above can significantly increase the first time load. It may be acceptable for the use case you are describing. Hope this helps!